# A bag of scrabble tile contains 5 Es, 4 As, 3 Ns and 2 Bs.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

I draw 4 tiles one by one from the bag as an ordered sample without replacement. Assume equally likely outcomes. Let C be the event that I get 2 Es, 1 A and 1 N. Compute P(c).

So I started by taking P(14,4) which gave me 24,024. Then, to account for repeated elements in the sample space (5 Es, 4 As, 3 Ns, 2 Bs), I figured I'd have to divide by $5!\cdot4!\cdot3!\cdot2!$. The problem is that this gave me a value less than 1. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I will come to your working but are you not finding probability of the event $C$? So it should be less than $1$, why is that wrong?

Comment: @MathLover Because I wasn't at that step yet, I was still in the process of cancelling out repeated combinations to get my total number of ways to draw the ordered samples of tiles.

Comment: $14 \choose 4$ is the total number of ways to draw $4$ tiles if the order does not matter.

Comment: @MathLover I would use that if I was looking for unordered samples, but that is not the case.

Comment: The question is to find probability so that may not necessary. In any case even if you did that, why are you dividing by $5!$ etc.? You have to consider the order in the $4$ tiles that you take out, not in $14$.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.  For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on MathJax notation](/help/notation), [MathJax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/259305) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773/290189).

Answer (score 2):

This is a question on probability so here is how you should go about it -

Sample space: $5 E, 4 A, 3 N, 2 B$

Event C of $4$ tiles:  $2 E, 1 A, 1 N$

So $P(C) = \displaystyle \frac{{5 \choose 2}{4 \choose 1}{3 \choose 1}}{14 \choose 4} = \frac{120}{1001}$

If you consider the order in your calculation, you will get to the same answer. In that case in total, you have $14$ choices for the first, $13$ for the next and so on ($ ^{14}P_4 $). For favorable cases, multiply your selection by $4!$ for possible arrangements of them.

$P(C) = \displaystyle \frac{{5 \choose 2}{4 \choose 1}{3 \choose 1} \ 4!}{14 \times 13 \times 12 \times 11} = \frac{120}{1001}$